# Subset a data table based on cell selection of another datatable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny app with 3 datatables. The first one contains only the 5th row with `Species` the 2nd table contains some random `Species` and the third table should get the selected cells from the first 2 tables and combines them into a new table. While the first seems to works fine the 2nd table selection seems to be wrong and that happens because it subsets by cell position and not by cell value.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable2"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable3")

  )

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(matrix(iris[,5]), 
                                            selection=list( target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable2 <- DT::renderDataTable(matrix(iris[c(25,78,67,45,90,66,78,9,8),5]), 
                                            selection=list(mode="single", target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable3 <- DT::renderDataTable(iris[c(input$myDatatable_cells_selected,input$myDatatable2_cells_selected),], 
                                             server = FALSE,
                                             rownames=FALSE)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See code below. You were trying to subset the data versus creating a new dataframe(which from above sounds like what you want) + you want to use `[tablename]_cell_clicked` which has a `row`, `column`, `value` list versus `[tablename]_cells_selected`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable2"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable3")

  )

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  dat1 <- reactive({
    matrix(iris[,5])
  })

  dat2 <- reactive({
    matrix(iris[c(25,78,67,45,90,66,78,9,8),5])
  })

  dat3 <- reactive({
    temp <- data.frame(results = c(input$myDatatable_cell_clicked$value, input$myDatatable2_cell_clicked$value))
  })




  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(dat1(), 
                                            selection=list( target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable2 <- DT::renderDataTable(dat2(), 
                                             selection=list(mode="single", target="cell"),
                                             server = FALSE,
                                             rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable3 <- DT::renderDataTable(dat3(), 
                                             server = FALSE,
                                             rownames=FALSE)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Updated based on OP's clarification

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
data("mtcars")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable2"),
    DT::dataTableOutput("myDatatable3")

  )

)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  dat1 <- reactive({
    matrix(iris[,5])
  })

  dat2 <- reactive({
    matrix(iris[c(25,78,67,45,90,66,78,9,8),5])
  })

  dat3 <- reactive({

    dat1row <- input$myDatatable_cells_selected
    dat2row <- c(25,78,67,45,90,66,78,9,8)[c(input$myDatatable2_cell_clicked$row)]


    temp <- iris[c(dat1row, dat2row),]
  })




  output$myDatatable <- DT::renderDataTable(dat1(), 
                                            selection=list( target="cell"),
                                            server = FALSE,
                                            rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable2 <- DT::renderDataTable(dat2(), 
                                             selection=list(mode="single", target="cell"),
                                             server = FALSE,
                                             rownames=FALSE)
  output$myDatatable3 <- DT::renderDataTable(dat3(), 
                                             server = FALSE,
                                             rownames=FALSE)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: maybe it was not clear by me but I want the whole row to be displayed in the 3rd table not just the selected value

Comment: Updated to your request. Your issue was you were trying to get the row for the 2nd table but the table rows are 1-9, it won't give you your original rows of the dataset (25, 78, etc). You just need to pick the right value out of the vector and there you go!

Comment: thanks but it just displays the last selected value from the 1st table while I need all the selected

Comment: Then just use part of your original answer using [tablename]_cells_selected. I've updated my answer to include it